# Items inside archive are not updating on archive url change though archive data is updated reactjs nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am now working on a react (nextjs) project. I have products and multilevel categories on the backend. I fetched the data from api and display them on `/categories/[slug].jsx`. A little detail of category and products for this category have been fetched and displayed.

If I visit the categories manually `e.g. http://localhost/categories/category-one`, it fetches the data correctly and works properly. In this case, I have a sidebar in this archive page that displays all available categories on the backend. If I click on each of the category link `e.g. http://localhost/categories/category-two` from the sidebar of `/category-one` archive page, path and category detail get updated but the products inside the new paths for the current category are not udpated. Only the products of previous category displayed. I have to reload the page to see the correct products of the category.

I tried to use useEffect to update but it didn't work. Maybe the way I did was wrong. Could anyone let me know how I could refresh the product list of the category on path change?

This is `/categories/[slug].jsx`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import ProductArchive from '/ProductArchive';

import { getCategory, getCategoryByHierarchy, getCategorySlugs } from '/libs/categories';
import { getProductsByCatIds, getProductsCountByCatIds } from '/libs/products';

const CategoryScreen = ({ category, productsByCatIds, productsCount, categories }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(productsByCatIds);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  const router = useRouter();

  const getMoreProducts = async () => {
    const moreProducts = await getProductsByCatIds({
      catId: category.term_id,
      perPage: 16,
      offset: products.length,
    });

    if (moreProducts.code === 'no_product') return;

    setProducts((products) => [...products, ...moreProducts]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('path got changed');
  }, [router.asPath]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHasMore(productsCount > products.length ? true : false);
  }, [productsCount, products]);

  return (
    <>
      <ProductArchive
        products={products}
        getMoreProducts={getMoreProducts}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        productsCount={productsCount}
        banner={{ heading: category.name, i2Text: category.name }}
        data={categories}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const paths = await getCategorySlugs();

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const category = await getCategory(params.slug);

  if (!category) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  const productsByCatIds = await getProductsByCatIds({
    catId: category.id,
    perPage: 16,
  });

  const productsCount = await getProductsCountByCatIds({
    catId: category.id,
  });

  const categories = await getCategoryByHierarchy();

  const data = { category, productsByCatIds, productsCount, categories };

  return {
    props: data || {},
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};

export default CategoryScreen;
```

This is `/ProductArchive.jsx`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import DefaultBanner from './DefaultBanner';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
import DefaultLoader from './DefaultLoader';
import { thousandSeparator } from '../../libs/functions/thousandSeparator';

const ProductArchive = ({ banner, products, getMoreProducts, hasMore, productsCount, data }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <DefaultBanner heading={banner.heading} i2Text={banner.i2Text} />

      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid-view">
          <div className="col-1">
            <Sidebar data={data} />
          </div>

          <div className="col-2">
            <div className="relative">
              {productsCount > 0 && (
                <small className="total">
                  Total: {thousandSeparator(productsCount)}
                </small>
              )}
            </div>
            {productsCount > 0 ? (
              <InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={products.length}
                next={getMoreProducts}
                hasMore={hasMore}
                loader={<DefaultLoader />}
                endMessage={<p></p>}
                scrollThreshold="0.5"
              >
                <div className="another-grid">
                  {products.length > 0 ? (
                    products.map((product, index) => {
                      return (
                        <ProductCard
                          key={product.id}
                          index={index}
                          product={product}
                        />
                      );
                    })
                  ) : (
                    <div>
                      <h4 className="text-xl">Oops... No products found.</h4>
                      <p className="mt-2 font-thin">
                        <Link href="/">
                          <a>Go back to homepage</a>
                        </Link>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </InfiniteScroll>
            ) : (
              <div>No products found.</div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ProductArchive;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) package by Vercel.

In the solution, I only fetched the first 16 products with getStaticProps and the rest are fetched with useSWRInfinite. You could use useSWR only as well if you don't need pagination or infinite load more. Hope this could be helpful for others.